# How to use string without double quotes around it via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very small problem but couldn't find the solution despite of 2 hours of searching.

What I have is a simple javascript variable which is

```
var route_name = db.FIELD_ROUTE_NAME;
```

and in another javascript file

```
var db = {
    FIELD_ROUTE_NAME: "fld_route_name",
    // another js constants
};
```

As you can see, route_name equals to "`fld_route_name`" (with quotes around because it's string, I know)

Is there any way I can use this without double quotes around, like just `fld_route_name` ?

EDIT:

```
 messages: { // custom messages for radio buttons and checkboxes
                fld_route_name: {
                    required: localize("at_least_5_characters"),
                },
```

Comment: What exactly you want?

Comment: ha ha but I don't think so.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If its a string you need quotes or double quotes otherwise it will think you want a variable

Comment: I need to use fld_route_name without quotes around it

Comment: `fld_route_name` is a value. How can it be used with quotes or without quotes? It's not an identifier.

Comment: `alert(db.FIELD_ROUTE_NAME)` - where do you see quotes in there?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way I can use this *without double quotes*

Yes, you can use simple quotes:

```
var db = {
    FIELD_ROUTE_NAME: 'fld_route_name',
    // another js constants
};
```

But you can't do

```
var db = {
    FIELD_ROUTE_NAME: fld_route_name,
    // another js constants
};
```

if `fld_route_name` variable is not defined.

Example:

```
var fld_route_name = "fld_route_name"; // the quotes still appear here
var db = {
    FIELD_ROUTE_NAME: fld_route_name,
    // another js constants
};
```

Comment: Well, changing FIELD_ROUTE_NAME: "fld_route_name" is not an option for me in this case, it's in dynamics of the whole project.

Comment: @FreshPro Why isn't `FIELD_ROUTE_NAME: "fld_route_name"` ok? I cannot understand what do you need.

Comment: var route_name = db.FIELD_ROUTE_NAME; -> Equals to "fld_route_name" right?   but what I need to use (in a specific page) is fld_route_name(without quotes). So I'm asking is there a way

Comment: @FreshPro Yes, `db.FIELD_ROUTE_NAME` will return `"fld_route_name"` (that is a string). When you define the constants you can put any values there, they are constants. What do you mean when saying *fld_route_name(without quotes)*?

Comment: As you can see, I need to use fld_route_name as value, not a string inside jquery

Comment: @FreshPro Ah, `db.FIELD_ROUTE_NAME` is a string, but it **doesn't contain** quotes inside of it. So, `FIELD_ROUTE_NAME: 'fld_route_name'` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have quotes around it, then it isn't a string literal but becomes an identifier instead. In that context, an identifier is a variable.

You can avoid the quotes if you define a suitable variable first.

```
var fld_route_name = "fld_route_name"

var db = {
    FIELD_ROUTE_NAME: fld_route_name,
    // another js constants
};
```

Or you could use single quotes instead of double quotes.

```
var db = {
    FIELD_ROUTE_NAME: 'fld_route_name',
    // another js constants
};
```

Comment: Isn't this hard-coding an identifier based on it's value? OP wants to use a _value_ without quotes, which doesn't make sense.